# Compile/Install libdvdcss on Mountain Lion

Tags: compiler-errors, osx-mountain-lion, configure

I downloaded the latest libdvdcss source and want to compile and then install on Mountain Lion.

I am getting hung up on ./configure.  It looks like I don't have the right bootstrap.

Any ideas on where to go from here?  Should I adjust "LT_INIT"? To what value?

Here's the output of ./configure.

```
BRETTs-Mac-Pro:libdvdcss brettmichaels$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
./configure: line 2853: syntax error near unexpected token `win32-dll'
./configure: line 2853: `LT_INIT(win32-dll)'
BRETTs-Mac-Pro:libdvdcss brettmichaels$
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. I could fix it on my System (GNU/Linux - Debian 7) by installing the libtool package. Have you checked if you have this tool (or an equivalent) installed? The LT_INIT macro doesn't seem to need any changes.
As stated in the INSTALL file, I had to executed the `aclocal` and `autoreconf -i` command after installing libtool. Afterwards the `configure` command ran through without any errors.